# Nested attributes form not showing in devise views Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have an app with a user model that can have many addresses. I want to be able to add an address to the user when they sign up via nested attributes. I am also using devise for the user model.

Models:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :addresses

accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses

end
```

Registration controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show]


def new
  resource = build_resource({})  
  resource.addresses.build
  respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new } 
 end

 def create
   super
 end



private 

def set_user
@user = User.find(params[id])

end

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :first_name,                  
:last_name, :phonenumber, :addresses_attributes => [:postcode,  
:housenumber, :streetname, :city, :town] )

   end
 end
```

Fields for form in registration view:

```
   <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |address|%>
  <%= address.input :housenumber %>
  <%= address.input :postcode %>
  <%= address.input :streetname%>
  <%= address.input :town%>
  <%= address.input :city%>
    <%end%>
```

Comment: did you figure out how to do this? Im stuck with the same problem

Comment: No I gave up on it and made the design different, although I did realise when working on a different aspect that my custom controller wasn't actually being used, and it was still using the devise one. I would suggest double checking that the right controller is being used, because I have a feeling that, that was the problem with mine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following method to your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Your code

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:email, :addresses_attributes => [:postcode, :housenumber, :streetname, :city, :town])
    end
  end
end
```

This allows you to permit nested attributes for the devise model. See the repo page and search for 'nested' for more info:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I tried adding that, and I read through the repo but couldn't find anything that seemed to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I trying to do the exact same thing pretty much...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but this may save someone in the future.
After implementing the `configure_sign_up_params`, you must use it in the action create so your `Users::RegistrationsController` should look like this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:show]
    before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

    # more code bellow...
    protected

      def configure_sign_up_params
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(
              :sign_up,
              keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation,
              # put any other keys in here                 
          ])
      end
end
```